# How to get the resource initator like chrome-dev-tools?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am making a javascript tracker using CefSharp.
While searching for a lot of solution, I could use a service worker to implement code like this that hijacking http/https requests, but it didn't work:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(async function(e) {
    var err = new Error();
    ccw.hhh(err.stack); // print call-stack info using my own js-object
  }());
});
```

Since I didn't create own web pages, so couldn't use code like `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')`.

And also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests is not working on CefSharp.

And `IResourceHandler::Open(IRequest ...) IRequest` provided by CefSharp not contains callstack and initator informations.

How can I get to the requests call stack informations in CefSharp?

Comment: What version are you using? What exactly is stopping you from using a service worker? You can execute JavaScript. Please also read https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: I could handle the service-worker problem using CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory provided cefsharp, but the service-worker could not trace the stack because it had a separate JavaScript context and could not use the registered JavaScript object. I solved this problem using chrome-devtools-protocol. https://github.com/rollrat/com-crawler/blob/master/com_crawler.Tool.CustomCrawler/chrome-devtools/ChromeDevtoolsEnvironment.cs